# Recover Dreamweaver Files

Tags: dreamweaver, restore, system-restore

I need help! I was just about to upload some new files to my site when I accidently pressed the get button instead of the put button...! Now all the changes are gone! How can I restore the file? Please help me! Thanks!

Comment: Have never used Dreamweaver, but going to go with "you can't recover files that have been overwritten".

Comment: @Graphain: puh...! Luck me I had the most important script copied so when I realized that I had it copied I just pasted it back again!

Comment: Very lucky, what a weird Dreamweaver behavior.

Answer (score 0):

As an answer to my own question I would actually agree with Graphain, "You can't recover files that have been overwritten". This would say that it's impossible to recover it. However if I wouldn't have saved the new file I could retrieve from a TEMP folder where it would be until the new file would be saved.

Dreamweaver automatically saved my new file, lucky me I had the most important script copied so I could just paste it back in again. So a tip for you guys who also had the same problem as I had would be to create a backup file for it before upload or copy the whole document and if something goes wrong you can just paste it back in again(1st step of backup).